# Jenkins Build Flow AND Build Pipeline plugins

Tags: jenkins

Will the [Build Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) still show the sequence of jobs properly if the jobs are run using [Build Flow](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) (including a repeated job)?

---

Here is pseudocode for our build flow:

```
build("Package")
build("Deploy", destination: "http://test") // deploy to our test environment
build("IntegrationTests", target: "http://test") // run automated tests
build("Deploy", destination: "http://stage") // deploy to stage
```

- **Package** will pull code from source control, compile it, and store it as an artifact
- **Deploy** will copy artifacts from the upstream **Package** job then copy it to the URL provided in the `destination` parameter
- **IntegrationTests** will run a suite of integration tests against the URL provided in the `destination` parameter.

Will the [Build Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Pipeline+Plugin) show this pipeline as 4 steps even though the **Deploy** job is repeated?

```
Package  =>  Deploy (test)  =>  IntegrationTests  =>  Deploy (stage)
```

Comment: Yes,as far as you are specifying upstream and downstream jobs in each of the build job you can repeat anything and  at any place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new solution, [which is being adopted with Jenkins 2.0](https://jenkins.io/2.0/#pipelines), is the [Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin). Also, CloudBees open-sourced their [Pipeline Stage View plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Stage+View+Plugin) which provides a visualization to the Pipeline plugin.